# Session tokens in PHP being cached by Joomla

Tags: php, session, caching, joomla

I'm using Joomla for a project, and there's some Ajax requests happening to populate data. I generate a Joomla session token in the PHP view, and tack this onto the URL of the Ajax request endpoint, which is also a PHP page, and validates the token before returning data.

Something like this:

```
// view.html.php
$script = "var ajaxurl = 'index.php?task=ajaxFunction&".JFactory::getSession()->getFormToken()."=1';";
$document->addScriptDeclaration($script);

// ajax.js
var request = new Request.JSON({
    url: ajaxurl,
    onException: function(headerName, value) {
        // etc.
    }
});

// controller
public function ajaxfunction()
{
    JRequest::checkToken('get') or die( 'Invalid Token!' );
    // do other stuff
}
```

This works just fine until caching is enabled.

The problem is that the `view.html.php` file, when Joomla uses its internal caching, is cached with the token already set-- so anytime a browser requests the page, it pulls the cached token along with it, meaning the controller will return an invalid Token error.

I know in earlier Joomla builds caching flat out didn't work. Is there a way to make this work in Joomla 2.5+, short of just disabling the Joomla cache? I can't find any way to exclude a single view from caching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you may want to send the request as POST instead of GET, which won't use Joomla caching.

**ajax.js**

```
var userToken = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].name;

var request   = new Request.JSON({
    url: 'index.php?task=ajaxFunction&'+ userToken +'=1',
    onException: function(headerName, value) {
        // etc.
    }
    onComplete: function(res) {
        // etc.
    }

}).post({});
```

**controller**

```
JRequest::checkToken('get') or die( 'Invalid Token!' );
```

Stick this at the top of your template file (before all other input tags), it will create a hidden input field containing a token, which will eventually be replaced with the non-cached one on render

**tmpl/default.php**

```
<?= JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
```

Comment: Well, the problem is that in your `view.html.php` that call to the `getFormToken` is the part that's cached-- that token is "hardcoded" and will always be wrong, regardless of whether it's sent by POST or GET.

Comment: Hi. You're right julio caching is very fragile thing. I've updated my answer.

Comment: getElementByTagName may not be the best option but should give you a clue. Other option would be to place the JHtml token in a div with ID, get the div in JavaScript by ID first then get its child input with our session token attribute. Either way joomla always replaces the hidden token input before printing it from cache

Comment: Brilliant stuff WooDzu-- thanks for sticking with it. You've earned the bounty and this tactic works great. Still seems that there should be a more "core" way to handle this in Joomla, similar to what was suggested by nietonfir-- but this will get me there.

Comment: Thx. I submitted a suggestion at Joomla to check for a paramater like NOCACHE in Get array to disable caching on any page. But since it hasnt been added I often use a custom plugin to do it

Comment: Any idea why `JHtml::_('form.token')` works when all it is is a wrapper for `JSession::getFormToken()`, which does not work (eg. gets cached) when called directly? Is this JHtml helper function excluded from caching in the actual Joomla cache mechanism?

Comment: See in JCache class, joomla searches for the whole input field and updates the token in it with preg_repleace before printing the buffer. Thats why these tokens are always up-to-date

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I work with Ajax and Joomla and really do not have this problem. Well, maybe the way you is working, is maybe better try a diferent way of do the cache, so if you really have no hope , just fork **System - Cache** from Joomla, and on your fork make it does not cache what you do not want. If in your project is possible to handle how you do your cache, you can also do not use Joomla Cache and use it with Varnish or similar.

I think it should be better than how you're doing: Joomla have one group to include one more "standard" way to work with AJAX, and you can see one Proof of Concept Here:

- https://github.com/betweenbrain/Joomla-Ajax-Interface

Discussion here

- https://groups.google.com/d/msg/joomla-dev-general/i1syYWshGsY/3udixCaRnRAJ

Also, another aproach about use of Ajax is here

- https://github.com/juliopontes/joomla-ajax-handle

Comment: Hi-- unfortunately hacking the core system cache is not an option.

Comment: Fork (create a copy, change and install) **is not** a hack in Joomla core.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what I'm saying. It is not an option to expect users to modify the core Joomla files.

Comment: well if you need to disable caching for particular view or task there in no other way than creating own caching pluging. So Luiz is right here

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the [method signature](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-platform/blob/11.4/libraries/joomla/session/session.php#L250) of `JSession::getFormToken()` you should be able to force a new token by calling `getFormToken(true)`.

This should circumvent any caching issues you're experiencing.

Comment: moreover it wont even let you submitt the request with caching off

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it in joomla with a very similar set up is inject the value with JavaScript. The page is cached without the token and JavaScript adds it before making the request

You can pass the value with cookies or another ajax request. Cookies  works best fort me

Comment: that sounds like what I'm looking for. Can you provide a bit of example?

Comment: I'm on a tablet currently so can't really type code well. Will be able to tomorrow